# Enity Framework With MySQL - config file could not be loaded

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to change SQL Database type from MSSQL to MySQL inside .NET web app.

I followed this:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

and updating Web.config files.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="AdWordsApi" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
...
</configuration>
...
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.EntityFramework">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=XYZ;Database=XYZ;Uid=XYZ;Password=XYZ;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When trying to Enable-Migrations I am getting:

> Checking if the context targets an existing database...
> System.InvalidOperationException: The DbConfiguration type 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.EntityFramework' specified in the application config file could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Nie można załadować typu 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration' z zestawu 'MySql.Data.EntityFramework'.
> w System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
> w System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
> w System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
> w System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationLoader.TryLoadFromConfig(AppConfig config)
> --- Koniec śladu stosu wyjątków wewnętrznych ---
> w System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationLoader.TryLoadFromConfig(AppConfig config)
> w System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForAssembly(Assembly assemblyHint, Type contextTypeHint)
> w System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.ScaffoldInitialCreateInternal(DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, String contextTypeName, String contextAssemblyName, String migrationsNamespace, Boolean auto, String migrationsDir)
> w System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.ScaffoldInitialCreate.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> w System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.b__0()
> w System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> The DbConfiguration type 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.EntityFramework' specified in the application config file could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information.```

I din't update any class, only configuration files so far. My context class looks like this:

```
namespace Repository.Models
{
    public class AppContext : IdentityDbContext, IAppContext
    {
        public AppContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public static AppContext Create()
        {
            return new AppContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

I tried modifying above class into with no luck:

```
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class AppContext : DbContext, IAppContext
    {
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        ...

        public AppContext()
          : base()
        {

        }

        // Constructor to use on a DbConnection that is already opened
        public AppContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
          : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            //modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You Need to Install The NuGet Package MySql.Data.Entity

2- Update the Configuration Type of DbContextFile:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEfConfiguration))]
public class AppDbContext : DbContext{.....}
```

3- Change the Connection String provider name to: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"

```
providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
```

4- Test With Migrations

As I See, the problem is that you need to modify the DbContext Class

Comment: 1. There is no MySql.Data.Entity package. There are MySql.Data.Entities, MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.EntityFramework. I installed MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.EntityFramework as was stated in the manual.

2. I tried to modify the class (added AppContext class above).

3. It is done.

Answer (score 0):

I think document at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html is not updated

Because https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/ is deprecated. Now official package is `MySql.Data.EntityFramework`

So we need to update config (`App.config` or `web.config`)

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.EntityFramework">
```

To

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.EntityFramework">
```